# How did i resolve these scout-apm + rails warning getting on heroku server during build deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

e: Calling `DidYouMean::SPELL_CHECKERS.merge!(error_name => spell_checker)' has been deprecated. Please call` DidYouMean.correct_error(error_name, spell_checker)' instead.
remote: I, [2022-09-07T13:32:05.994002 #19]  INFO -- : Raven 3.1.2 ready to catch errors
remote: [Scout] [09/07/22 13:32:06 +0000 release.7924 (19)] WARN Exception loading instruments:
remote: [Scout] [09/07/22 13:32:06 +0000 release.7924 (19)] WARN : undefined method `call' for class` Redis::Client'
remote:
remote:               alias_method :call_without_scout_instruments, :call
remote:               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote: Did you mean?  caller
remote: [Scout] [09/07/22 13:32:06 +0000 release.7924 (19)] WARN : ["/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/scout_apm-5.3.1/lib/scout_apm/instruments/redis.rb:40:in `alias_method'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/scout_apm-5.3.1/lib/scout_apm/instruments/redis.rb:40:in` block in install'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/scout_apm-5.3.1/lib/scout_apm/instruments/Redis.rb:29:in `class_eval'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/scout_apm-5.3.1/lib/scout_apm/instruments/Redis.rb:29:in` install'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/scout_apm-5.3.1/lib/scout_apm/instrument_manager.rb:82:in `install_instrument'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/scout_apm-5.3.1/lib/scout_apm/instrument_manager.rb:37:in` install!'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/scout_apm-5.3.1/lib/scout_apm/agent.rb:41:in `install'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/scout_apm-5.3.1/lib/scout_apm.rb:223:in` block in class:Railtie'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in` run'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'", "/app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in` block in tsort_each'", "/app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'", "/app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in` each_strongly_connected_component_from'", "/app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'", "/app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in` each'", "/app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'", "/app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in` each_strongly_connected_component'", "/app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'", "/app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in` tsort_each'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in` initialize!'", "/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in` require'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in` require'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in` load_dependency'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in` require_environment!'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/application.rb:523:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in` block in execute'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in` execute'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in` synchronize'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in` block in invoke_prerequisites'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in` invoke_prerequisites'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:218:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in` synchronize'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in` block in invoke_prerequisites'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in` invoke_prerequisites'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:218:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in` synchronize'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in` invoke'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in` block (2 levels) in top_level'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in` block in top_level'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in` top_level'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in` standard_exception_handling'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in` invoke'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in` require'", "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'", "/app/bin/rails:4:in` '"]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was an error with the latest redis client: https://github.com/scoutapp/scout_apm_ruby/issues/458

It has been fixed in the latest version of the gem (5.3.2).